# Iterate over a pair of iterables, sorted by an attribute

Tags: python, iterable-unpacking

One way (the fastest way?) to iterate over a pair of iterables `a` and `b` in sorted order is to chain them and sort the chained iterable:

```
for i in sorted(chain(a, b)):
    print i
```

For instance, if the elements of each iterable are:

```
a: 4, 6, 1
b: 8, 3
```

then this construct would produce elements in the order

```
1, 3, 4, 6, 8
```

However, if the iterables iterate over objects, this sorts the objects by their memory address.  Assuming each iterable iterates over the same type of object,

1. What is the **fastest** way to iterate over a particular
   attribute of the objects, sorted by this attribute?
2. What if the attribute to be chosen differs between iterables?  If iterables `a` and `b` both iterate over objects of type `foo`, which has attributes `foo.x` and `foo.y` of the same type, how could one iterate over elements of `a` sorted by `x` and `b` sorted by `y`?

For an example of #2, if

```
a: (x=4,y=3), (x=6,y=2), (x=1,y=7)
b: (x=2,y=8), (x=2,y=3)
```

then the elements should be produced in the order

```
1, 3, 4, 6, 8
```

as before.  Note that only the `x` attributes from `a` and the `y` attributes from `b` enter into the sort and the result.

Comment: For your second question: How are the sorts merged? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @TimPietzcker since according to the question `foo.x` and `foo.y` are of the same type, intuitively I'd say OP expects the whole lot to be sorted on an imaginary `foo.z` equal to the relevant attribute for each iterable.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus Yes, basically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tim Pietzcker has already answered for the case where you're using the same attribute for each iterable. If you're using different attributes of the same type, you can do it like this (using complex numbers as a ready-made class that has two attributes of the same type):

In Python 2:

```
>>> a = [1+4j, 7+0j, 3+6j, 9+2j, 5+8j]
>>> b = [2+5j, 8+1j, 4+7j, 0+3j, 6+9j]
>>> keyed_a = ((n.real, n) for n in a)
>>> keyed_b = ((n.imag, n) for n in b)
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> sorted_ab = zip(*sorted(chain(keyed_a, keyed_b), key=lambda t: t[0]))[1]
>>> sorted_ab
((1+4j), (8+1j), (3+6j), 3j, (5+8j), (2+5j), (7+0j), (4+7j), (9+2j), (6+9j))
```

Since in Python 3 `zip()` returns an iterator, we need to coerce it to a list before attempting to subscript it:

```
>>> # ... as before up to 'from itertools import chain'
>>> sorted_ab = list(zip(*sorted(chain(keyed_a, keyed_b), key=lambda t: t[0])))[1]
>>> sorted_ab
((1+4j), (8+1j), (3+6j), 3j, (5+8j), (2+5j), (7+0j), (4+7j), (9+2j), (6+9j))
```

Comment: You could always wrap the zip function in a list() for python3, that will contain the entire output of the iterator thus:
`list(zip(*sorted(chain(keyed_a, keyed_b), key=lambda t: t[0])))[1]`

Comment: @Ole yes, that's a much better idea. Updated accordingly :-)

Answer (score 2):

Answer to question 1: You can provide a `key` attribute to [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted). For example if you want to sort by the object's `.name`, then use

```
sorted(chain(a, b), key=lambda x: x.name)
```

As for question 2: I guess you'd need another attribute for each object (like `foo.z`, as suggested by Zero Piraeus) that can be accessed by `sorted()`, since that function has no way of telling where the object it's currently sorting used to come from. After all, it is receiving a new iterator from `chain()` which doesn't contain any information about whether the current element is from `a` or `b`.